# Measure Page bandwidth usage

Tags: java, networking, optimization, bandwidth, page-size

I want to see how much data is being send and received when I request for a page of my java web application. Is there any way to track it?

It runs on IE and don't support other browsers [ophs...feels bad about it. :(  ].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since IE is the only supported browser, you can try IE extension such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [HttpWatch](http://www.httpwatch.com/). Both will give you the statistics of data send/receive for each web request.